# Set default webpage for website on Microsoft Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, hosting

I recently set up a website on azurewebsites.net.

But when I go to the url http:/website.azurewebsites.net/
it doesn't load.

But when I go to http:/website.azurewebsites.net/home.aspx it loads.

What I want is that
if a user goes to  http:/website.azurewebsites.net/ it loads with the home.aspx content or get redirected to http:/website.azurewebsites.net/home.aspx

This doesn't work

```
 <system.webServer>
   <defaultDocument>
     <files>
       <clear />
       <add value="Default.aspx" />
     </files>
   </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Sorry here's the actual link http://rathgarfantasyhockey.azurewebsites.net/default.aspx which works fine, but when you go to http://rathgarfantasyhockey.azurewebsites.net HTTP error 404, `The resource cannot be found` is displayed.

Can anyone help??

Comment: Can you add a comment as to what made your default document begin to work?

Comment: I voted up the question because I had the same problem but did not have the <clear /> in my <files> section.  Adding that solved the problem for me, but user1625190 already had that so I don't know what his resolution was.  Incidentally adding 'enabled=true' to the <defaultDocument> tag as suggested below had no effect in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2010/07/22/how-to-set-a-default-page-to-a-windows-azure-web-role-app-silverlight-asp-net-etc.aspx

```
<defaultDocument> 
          <files>                           
             <clear/>                           
             <add value="Default.aspx"/>                      
          </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Should Work. Or you could Type to Url map it. To do that check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: Adding `<clear/>` allowed me to successfully specify a default document.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using MVC or Web API, add the following line in RegisterRoutes():

```
   routes.IgnoreRoute("");
```

This solved my problem. Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. I tried the other solutions, but it didn't work until I added this.

Answer (score 4):

If you app is a MVC application, it looks for the default controller instead of default pages.

So you must map a route in RouteConfig. In my case,I wanted to load the site with an index.html page, so I did:

RouteConfig.cs file:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =    UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And in my HomeController, Index Action, write this code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect("/index.html");
    }
```

This works fine in Azure with a Shared Site. I hope this will help you.

Comment: You can also add route annotations for better control
```
 [Route("")]      // Combines to define the route template "Home"
 [Route("Index")] // Combines to define the route template "Home/Index"
 [Route("/")]     // Does not combine, defines the route template ""
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a typo?

You have:

```
<add value="Default.aspx" />
```

But you said that your "home page" that works is `/home.aspx`.

If you want for `/home.aspx` to be displayed when the user goes to `http:/website.azurewebsites.net/`, then I can think of several ways for you to accomplish that.

Since you have `Default.aspx` as your `defaultDocument`, you can rename `home.aspx` to `Default.aspx` and when someone goes to http:/website.azurewebsites.net/ the contents of `Default.aspx` will be displayed.

If you need to keep `home.aspx` named as `home.aspx` for some reason, then as you requested if you want for `http:/website.azurewebsites.net/` to redirect to `/home.aspx` then create a file called `Default.aspx` in the root directory and edit it to contain `Response.Redirect("home.aspx", false);`.  A complete example for this type of page is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.80).aspx.

Update:

Try adding `enabled="true"` to your `defaultDocument` XML tag.  See the example below from http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument

```
 <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="home.html" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Sorry no, its not it, the page is /Default.aspx

Comment: hi, thanks for getting back to me but i did that but still it doesnt work. if you go to http://rathgarfantasyhockey.azurewebsites.net/ it still displays an error. If you go to  http://rathgarfantasyhockey.azurewebsites.net/Default.aspx it does display/redirect to the home page like you said

Comment: Updated answer to include changing `defaultDocument` XML tag to `<defaultDocument enabled="true">`