# How to deploy Node.js VS project into Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment

I just want to try some new stuff using Node.js in Visual Studio 2013. I created a new project using "**Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 Application**" template. Without adding any my own code, it runs fine locally. Then, I tried to deploy it into Azure as a website.

When I use Publish menu from VS, I got stuck at sign in. It keeps complaining "**no microsoft azure subscriptions were added. sign in with an account that has subscriptions**". But I have the correct account, and based on this [Q/A](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/partners/azuretoolssigninfaq.htm), I do see my subscription shown as "Visual Studio Premium with MSDN" and Role as "Service administrator" from the Setting tab in the Windows Azure Management Portal when I log in from website. What's problem?

Then, I tried to deploy it using LocalGit as shown in [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/). After some struggle, it seems to have deployed. However, when I try to open the url, I got the error "**You do not have permission to view this directory or page.**" For which I couldn't find answer either. So, I'm stuck again.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `server.js` is in the root of the repository. Else [Set default webpage for website on Microsoft Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126518/set-default-webpage-for-website-on-microsoft-windows-azure)

This part of [`package.json`](http://browsenpm.org/package.json) is also critical:

```
  "main": "main.js",  // required script
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"  // npm start command
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.12.3"  // must be on platform
  },
```