# Map a sub web page to its own domain (IIS 8, Azure VM 2012R2, Drupal CMS)

Tags: iis, drupal, dns

I am hosting a web site on an azure VM (IIS 8). The site (lets say www.site1.com) has its own domain name association and is built on Drupal. I want to map a sub page (within the same Drupal instance) to its own domain. For example I want the page that currently appears under: www.site1.com/page1, to also appear under: www.site2.com.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the response to this question below pretty much covers it for you

[Set default webpage for website on Microsoft Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126518/set-default-webpage-for-website-on-microsoft-windows-azure)

You can set this up via the location paths

```
<location path=”webFolder1″>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value=”myDefalutPage.aspx” />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
<location path=”webFolder2″>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value=” myDefalutPage.aspx” />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

This way you can cover both the domains by just changing your values for files and where its pointing to.

Refer to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2010/07/22/how-to-set-a-default-page-to-a-windows-azure-web-role-app-silverlight-asp-net-etc/) for more information.