# Azure not taking index.html as executable entry point

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

Developed and hosted a node.js application in azure and but it loads my application only when we write index.html after domain ends, for example https://mydomain.azure.net/index.html, how could we make it working without giving that index.html file there

Hope to have an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default webpage for website on Microsoft Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126518/set-default-webpage-for-website-on-microsoft-windows-azure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure your website works when a visitor goes to https://mydomain.azure.net without specifying a page name, you should be sure that the top level of your website contains a file named "index.html". The file must be at the top level; the Web server won't be able to find the file if it's inside a folder or directory you published.